# I can install windows but not ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb

My brother ask me to format and reinstall windows and ubuntu in his Toshiba Satellite L745D. With windows all was good, but when I tried to install ubuntu I can not. In the installation of ubuntu, the systems seems to create partitions correctly, but then it throws me the errors "Errno 30 read only file system" or "errno 5 input/output error".

I know that there are anothers post about that errors but anyone have solved my problem. This is the things that I have proved:

- I have check the md5sum of ubuntu 14.04 and it's good.
- Proved with ubuntu, mint and zorin.
- Used Unebootin (windows and ubuntu), Lili (windows), and the command dd to create the boot usb.
- I have prove 3 different usb.
- I have run badblocks and 0 errores, testmemo and the same.
- I have change the memory ram and still not work.
- With the same usb I can install ubuntu in another laptops.
- I have format de hard drive and install ubuntu but still the same error.
- I change the partition ext4 for ext2 and it seems install but  ubuntu don't install grub.

I ran the following commands based on suggestions in the comments:

```
$ grep -Fe ntfs -e fuse /proc/mounts
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/999/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999 0 0

$ ls -ld /media/live/c1d96d80-5d12-43ad-9700-98293ada982b
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 18 14:01 /media/live/c1d96d80-5d12-43ad-9700-98293ada982b`

$ sudo touch /media/live/c1d96d80-5d12-43ad-9700-98293ada982b/foobar.txt
```

The last command resulted in an empty file `/media/live/c1d96d80-5d12-43ad-9700-98293ada982b/foobar.txt`.

Comment: Gert might be on the right track with his answer. To confirm it, can you please boot the Ubuntu installation medium and run the "Try Ubuntu" option, then try to access (or "mount" in Unix lingo) your Windows partition(s) in writeable mode? Are there any error messages? What's the output of `grep -Fe ntfs -e fuse /proc/mounts` and `sudo lsblk -f`? If you need help with this and can't find relevant resources to help you, give me a ping.

Comment: Better I left you a terminal's screenshot http://2.1m.yt/eL5KCkw.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Working that particular NTFS partition seems to work just fine. How about the other ones? They all need to be mountable flawlessly for the Ubuntu installer to be able to resize them.

Comment: I have checked the partition for Ubuntu and I can't write in it. It's mount but I can't modify. Sorry for respond late, I hope you still help me.

Comment: How are you trying to "write" to those file systems? What's the particular error message? Is it about lack of permission or the file-system being read-only or something entirely different? Please mount *all* of the NTFS partitions in question and re-run `grep -Fe ntfs -e fuse /proc/mounts`.

Comment: In the partition of ubuntu I tried create a new document with the mount disk but I can´t. It doesn't throws me an error but checking the permissions is just for root.
I tried to change the permissions with chmod 777, then it copy and install the system, but almost at the end it throws an error and say maybe it's a problem with the hd and cancel the installation.

Comment: Please mount the partition in question, run the command from my previous comments as well as `ls -ld <MOUNTPOINT>` and `sudo touch <MOUNTPOINT>/foobar.txt`. What is the output of those commands?

Comment: I have done what you say. The output are in the question. The last command create foobar file but it`s empty.

Comment: According to those results the NTFS file system is definitely writeable from Linux. Can you please post the output of `sudo lsblk -f` so we can verify, that there are partitions available for the Ubuntu installer to use? Sometimes the automatic partitioning doesn't work and it's necessary and more reliable to use manual partitioning.

Comment: I delete all partitions and tried install ubuntu from zero. It didn't work, still the same error. I'm tired to try. :/

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by Windows. I assume that you are running Windows 8/8.1/10. Those Windows versions use a technology to put the partition in a hibernation mode. With other words, Windows protects itself from getting shrinked, as Microsoft rather wants you to use Windows than Linux. (The bastards!) Anyway, you are able to disable the hibernation by using a Command Prompt as Administrator under Windows and executing the following command: `powercfg.exe -h off`. That should do the trick. If it's still not working, post your question here, and I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for replied. It's neither Windows 8 nor 10, it's 7. I proved that commman bit it didn't work :/